# When do we use " Have/has been not" and Have/has not been"?

Tags: verbs

I search through some pages and find that both will work. Is it so? How?

Comment: You can't answer "When did you last visit San Francisco?" with "I have been not [there]." And you can't say "I have been not well." Are you referring to longer auxiliary constructions?

Comment: Not for longer auxiliary constructions.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You use it when you need to and you do not use *has been not*.

Example:

> I **have been** working.

or

> I **have not** got the chance to work today.

You really don't need to use *has been not*. Use *have not* instead.

Comment: Huh?  You absolutely need to use "has not" when using third person pronouns like he or she.  "She has not had the chance to work today."